# Sharepoint 2010 custom workflow activity migration to Sharepoint 2013 - Foundation

Tags: android-activity, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, workflow, sharepoint-2013

I have developed a custom sharepoint 2010 action and succesfully deployed through wsp

ADD-SPSolution, Install-SPSsolution + modification of web.config for port 80 and deployment was successful and I see this action also in Designer and action can be used within workflow.

I need to deploy it to Sharepoint 2013 foundation workflow platform 2010, so I used the same process, deployment to GAC, GlobalDeployment, compatibilityMode 14,15.

I also added authorized type to web.config, but I can not see activity in sharepoint designer 2013.

I created developement server Sharepoint 2013, I have created the activity on this new dev server and succesfully deployed to dev server, but despite this, I can not deploy it to production server as mentioned at the begining of this paragraph.

The only difference is that developement servers (SP Foundation 2010/2013) use PORT 80 /HTTP/ and production server uses port 443/HTTPS.

Is there any difference when deploying to this web aplication with SSL/TLS configured? Do I need to modify somehow source code? Or installation process?

I have lost 2 days and I have seen probably all forums in the web...

Kind regards and thank for help upfront.

Answer (score 0):

This might be silly, but have you activated the feature that contains the workflow activity on the particular production site?  SPD reads from the site.

Close SPD.

Check your %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\WebsiteCache and %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Web Server Extensions\Cache - clear out the site that your SPD has cached and then restart - see if SPD brings down the site definitions again.